# How to integrate Glide with onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android

I have an adapter that displays user name and a user image. My User class has a getter method to get the user id, and the user image uri (from Firebase). But how to set the image to image view? Right now I set the user name simply by using setText:

```
      @Override
      public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
          myHolder = holder;
          User user = mDataset.get(position);  
          myHolder.userNameTextView.setText(user.getUsername()); 
//how to integrate Glide here? assuming I have a getter method which returns the user image uri as String?
```

This Glide implementation works for me(on a separate activity, not on the adapter):

```
       Glide.with(this /* context */)
                .load(uri)
                .into(test);
```

Now assume I have a getter method in the User class which returns the image Uri, how to integrate it in the `OnBindViewHolder`? I can't make it work together

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special to use Glide with RecyclerView. The only concern is getting ahold of a `Context` object to pass to the `Glide.with()` call, but every `ViewHolder` has a field called `itemView` and every View has a `getContext()` method, so you can use those.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    User user = mDataset.get(position);  
    holder.userNameTextView.setText(user.getUsername());

    String uri = user.getAvatarUri(); // or whatever you want
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(uri).into(holder.imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Glide.with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(YourImage)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.splash_background)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .into(holder.imageLogoBooking);
```